# Is there a logspace function in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

tensorflow provides linspace but not logspace. Is there any reason for that?
I know I can use numpy for that but I was just curious about the reason behind it.

Comment: If you see the [source code of `logspace`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/function_base.py#L173-L266) you will see it's trivial to implement it in TensorFlow. They probably weren't convinced by the NumPy function API and instead preferred to let users decide how to build their logspace.

Comment: i totally agree